# Local variable name in setup_postdata()

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes, variables

I am new in wordpress, I was using setup_postdata() method inside of a template file which was being called via shortcode function. I have not used global $post in my function.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'new_shortcode' ) ) :
    function featured_posts_shortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
        ob_start();
        get_template_part("page-contents/section","abc");
        return ob_get_clean();   
    }
    add_shortcode( 'new', 'new_shortcode' );
endif;
```

Template file code part:

Not Working:

```
$my_post = get_post($my_post_id);
setup_postdata($my_post);        // Does not work.
```

Working:

```
$post = get_post($my_post_id);
setup_postdata($post);        // Works.
```

When I use setup_postdata($my_post), it does not set the global post to my post, but when I use setup_postdata($post) it sets the global post to my post.

How can a parameter name can effect a function?
Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) for `setup_postdata()`:

> `setup_postdata()` does **not** assign the global `$post` variable so it’s important that you do this yourself. Failure to do so will cause problems with any hooks that use any of the above globals in conjunction with the `$post` global, as they will refer to separate entities.

So the reason `$my_post` doesn't work is that functions you are using are depending on a variable named `$post`, but it is not defined. `setup_postdata()` does not set this variable. You need to do this yourself by defining `$post`, which should be `global $post`.